# Avoiding duplication between multiple event handlers

Tags: jquery, event-handling, code-duplication

I have two event handlers, one of which performs a duplicate action to part of the other. How would I refactor this script so that I could avoid the duplication?

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
    //Detect height of header image
    var headerHeight = $('.header-img').height();
    if (headerHeight > 0) {
        $('header').css({'position': 'fixed'});
        $('footer').css({'position': 'relative', 'top': headerHeight});
    }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    //Recalculate headerHeight if browser is resized
    var headerHeight = $('.header-img').height();
    $('footer').css({'position': 'relative', 'top': headerHeight});
});
```

Comment: You could create functions for the parts that you feel are duplicated and just call those functions when necessary.